# Getting the block id of where a value is stored

Tags: blockchain, storage

let's say I have a contract such as

```
contract Example {
   mapping (uint256 => string) messages;
   uint256 currentMessage = 0;

   function addMessage (string calldata message) external returns (uint256){
      messages[currentMessage] = message;
      return ++currentMessage;
   }

}
```

Is there a way to be able to point out to whoever called `addMessage` which block id on the chain now stores the `message` that they just added?

Comment: What do you mean by "block id"? Storage in ethereum is handled by a patricia trie.

Comment: @ismael let's say I want to provide a link to etherscan where this info can show, even in binary form

Comment: The easiest will be to provide the transaction hash. Etherscan shows the state changes. It is difficult to interpret for anyone unless you known what you are looking at.